# Concourse publishing meta data

Tags: concourse

Is there any best practise for publishing meta data, like a test coverage report, via Concourse? Zipping and putting to a git repo is not that nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like metadata would fall into the category of build artifacts and could be pushed to an object store via a resource like the included s3 resource or [s3-resource-simple](https://github.com/18F/s3-resource-simple).

[The docs](https://concourse.ci/single-page.html#versioned-s3-artifacts) have an example of using the included s3 resource. These [outputs could also be downloaded locally from a job](https://concourse.ci/single-page.html#taking-artifacts-from-the-build-with---output).